# Found unexpected null pointer value while trying to cast value of type 'UIApplication' (0x1ba22ac10) to 'NSObject' (0x1ba227d18)

Tags: ios, swiftui

On `init()` of my  SwiftUI `App` file I call some code (that's also called at other times in my app) that has the following piece of code in it:

```
await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
      var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
      cancellable =  UIApplication.shared.publisher(for: \.applicationState)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .filter { $0 != .background }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .first()
        .sink { _ in
          cancellable?.cancel()
        } receiveValue: { value in
          continuation.resume(with: .success(value))
        }
    }
```

This is supposed to wait until the `applicationState` is not in the `background` before continuing. This works fine when used in other areas of my code after applicationDidFinishLaunching. However, not in `init()` of the app. This actually crashes my app with the error:

`Found unexpected null pointer value while trying to cast value of type 'UIApplication' (0x1ba22ac10) to 'NSObject' (0x1ba227d18)`

Why?

UPDATE

This was being performed in an async function, which is why it was crashing. If I change this to a @MainActor isolated function, it works. Weird.

Comment: What is the reason for that cumbersome async/await / Combine expression rather than observing `.onChange` of [`scenePhase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase)?

Comment: Well this code is actually in a separate library I've created that doesn't use SwiftUI so I can't use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftUI, Main entry point runs like below.

1. static App.main.
2. App.init.
3. internal instance method App.run.
4. `UIApplicationMain`(this is the place where actual UIApplication is created and launched)

Which means `UIApplication.shared` is nil in `App.init()`.

However marking that operation as `@MainActor` actually delay the call.
At least until Swift 5.8 `@MainActor` is controlled by `DispatchQueue.main` and `DispatchQueue.main` have two mode. RunLoopMode and DispatchQueueMode.
In normal UIFramework DispatchQueue.main is controlled by Main RunLoop.
And UIKit controlls the Main RunLoop after UIApplication is created. So if you isolate the async operation to MainActor inside App.init. That Task will be delayed until `UIApplicationMain` is called. So this it the reason why MainActor isolation works.